# What happens when I don't pay my loan?

Tags: american-truck-simulator

My bank gave me a small loan of a 130k. I pay about 3k back every day, however I wonder what would happen if I didn't have money that day to pay it back.

What happens when I don't pay my loan?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you get to far into the red -100,000 i believe the bank gives you an amount of time before they will impound all your properties and trucks etc.. In short, you start at 0 again and have to do quick jobs and build up. its the ultimate end game really, or more like a reset.
Thats about all that happens. you just end up back at 0 money having to do quick jobs.

Answer (score 2):

Your loan repayments are deducted automatically, so there is no option not to pay them as far as I'm aware. It is possible for your account to dip into the red (into debt), and at this point your loan may be withheld.

If you are in the red for too many days, you will go bankrupt.

Comment: This doesn't really answer what happens when I don't have enough money. Basically, are there any consequences of account dipping into red?